# Benchmark datasets for regression on categorical features

Tags: data-request, machine-learning

There are a number of widely used benchmark datasets for machine learning algorithms available, but most of them are for regression or classification on numeric features.

I'm looking to test an algorithm that performs regression on categorical input features. Are there any readily available benchmark datasets that fit this description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good place to start is browsing the [UC Irvine Machine Learning Repository](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.php).  Note that you can sort by dataset task and attribute types.